# DetailsView binds to columns in database and asp:bound columns resulting in duplicate columns shown?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sqldatasource, detailsview

I have a DetailsView that has a Fields element and some bound columns.  The DetailsView is bound to a SqlDataSource.  Code on dev and in Environment B is exactly the same, but on dev, I am seeing the columns from the database as well as columns that are bound, so it results in a duplicate columns shown.  In Environment B, this is not happening, so I am wondering if it is a data issue, but I am not sure where to start or look?

```
<asp:DetailsView id="dv" runat="server" DataSourceID="sql" DataKeyNames="Id" OnDataBound="dv_DataBound" OnItemInserted="dv_ItemInserted" OnModeChanged="dv_ModeChanged" HeaderText="Add New" AutoGenerateInsertButton="true">
<Fields>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="sName" />
</Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

The above DetailsView will generate a form that displays label `sName` with a textbox next to it and another label `Name` with a TextBox next to it, but the exact same code in Environment B only generates the label `Name` with a TextBox next to it.  This has me thinking it is a data issue, but I can't pinpoint where to start looking.  The `SqlDataSource.SelectCommand` is just a stored proc that is similar to:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_1
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the DetailsView has something like AutoGenerateColums in gridview?

Comment: No, but Environment B does not have that as well and it does not generate all the columns.  That does fix it, but I am curious to why Environment B generates properly and dev does not.